# Travis CI QUnit build fail with ReferenceError on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, travis-ci, qunit

My node QUnit Travis CI build (see [.travis.yml](https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/blob/develop/.travis.yml)) [fail miserably](https://travis-ci.org/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/builds/323560211) with this error :

```
Running "qunit:files" (qunit) task
Testing test/unit/iframeTracker-jQuery1.html FF
   global failure
   Message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
   file:///home/travis/build/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/src/jquery.iframetracker.js:184
```

QUnit test code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.3.3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
        <!-- ... (some iframe) -->
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../src/jquery.iframetracker.js"></script>
    <script src="iframeTracker_test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why, because it works fine [in the browser](http://cdn.rawgit.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/develop/test/unit/iframeTracker-jQuery1.html) and within node locally (tested on Windows and Linux/Docker) :

```
docker run -ti --rm -v "$(pwd):/app" -w /app node:9 npm install
docker run -ti --rm -v "$(pwd):/app" -w /app node:9 npm test
```

I suspected CDNs (`code.jquery.com` and `ajax.googleapis.com`) to be responsible for this issue (I don't know if travis build environments have access to the internet) but I found some jQuery/QUnit builds (with [similar setup](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [using CDN](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/test/index.html#L15)) that works : https://travis-ci.org/fengyuanchen/cropper/builds/314789410

Can anyone explain me what's wrong with my build ?

Comment: You're on the right track obviously, jQuery isn't being included. Can you share the QUnit html file you're using?

Comment: The QUnit test file is here : https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/blob/develop/test/unit/iframeTracker-jQuery1.html. Test URL : http://cdn.rawgit.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/develop/test/unit/iframeTracker-jQuery1.html

Comment: Lining to code is not a preferred method on Stack Overflow, can you please edit the question to include the code? The reason is that if someone else has a similar issue and those links no longer work, then they can't see what the problem was, making it more difficult to find answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from `ajax.googleapis.com` to `code.jquery.com` CDN solved the Travis CI build.

I didn't found any official information about this in Travis CI documentation and issue tracker, but it seems that Travis build environments has some network restriction. It would be nice to have some quote on that from Travis staff, for example a list of allowed or denied CDNs.